# Rails 3, :json => @model.to_json OR :json => @model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I just wandered the difference between:

```
format.json { render :json => @post, :include => [ :user ] }
```

...and

```
format.json { render :json => @post.to_json(:include => [ :user ]) }
```

They both seem to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the same. if you have a look at actionpack `renderers.rb` you will see how it works:

```
add :json do |json, options|
  json = json.to_json(options) unless json.kind_of?(String)
  json = "#{options[:callback]}(#{json})" unless options[:callback].blank?
  self.content_type ||= Mime::JSON
  json
end
```