# Rails "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" in to_json method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override to_json in Rails 2.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572284/override-to-json-in-rails-2-3-5)

lib/responses.rb

```
module Responses
class Response
    def to_json
       JSON.pretty_generate(self)
    end
end

class ErrorResponse < Response
    def initialize(cause)
        self[:type]="Error"
        self[:casue]=cause

    end
end
class DataResponse < Response
    attr_accessor :data

end
end
```

This is used by the controller:

```
 response=Responses::DataResponse.new
 response.data=someData

 render :json => response
```

Now I am getting an error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` in `lib/responses.rb:3:in to_json`.
Why? There is no argument passed to the `to_json` which is implicitly called by `render :json`. So where is my mistake?

Comment: and connected to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557307/rails-3-json-model-to-json-or-json-model

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its because in Rails when you render with json, the method to_json will receive options.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
def to_json(options = {})
   JSON.pretty_generate(self, options)
end
```

Comment: ty. Renamed the method to `as_json_response` to avoid recursion issues, and used the method body of your post. Now the controller looks as following: `render :json => response.as_json_response`. Everything works fine now.